# Executar procedure oracle no sql developer

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Sei que pode parecer uma pergunta meio besta, mas ja procurei no google tb e nao achei nada concreto, possuo uma procedure onde a chamada dela é assim:

```
  PROCEDURE pr_rel_saldo(p_codigocliente IN NUMBER,
                                         P_data_inicio IN DATE,
                                         p_data_fim IN DATE,
                                         p_saida              OUT saida_cursor);
```

Como faço para testar ela pelo sql developer, ou seja, somente para executar mesmo, pra ver o resultado que está retornando.

Agradeço!!

Comment: já tentou `execute pr_rel_saldo` passando os parâmetros?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim

Comment: e qual o erro? é somente isso... pode tentar uma forma initerativa tbm, clica no lado equerdo encontro o nome da procedure, botão direito e "run", vai abrir uma tela para informar os parametros e executar. Faz tempo que não uso o plsql developer, então pde ter mudado algo

Comment: @RicardoPontual o erro é : PLS-00201: o identificador 'PR_REL_SALDO' deve ser declarado

Comment: Com a SP selecionada clique no icone de executar (botão verdinho) , prencha os parametros e dê ok , em "variáveis de saída" terá o resultado.

Comment: se nem achou a proc, não está faltando colocar o nome do schema, namespace, nada disso?

Comment: Ela ta dentro de uma package, tem diferença ?

Comment: E eu nao estou usando o PLSQL estou usando o SQL Developer

Comment: No caso passei 3 argumentos, que sao o de entrada, o de saida tb preciso passar ?

Comment: O de saída é o retorno , naxsaída , nunca usei em packages. Alías descobri esta opção tem pouco tempo.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode chamar ela da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE
    ww_saida saida_cursor;
BEGIN

  pr_rel_saldo(p_codigocliente => 1,
               P_data_inicio => sysdate,
               p_data_fim => sysdate,
               p_saida => ww_saida);
END;
```

Se essa procedure faz parte de um package, adicione o nome dela na frente da chamada.
Essa procedure deve ser publica.
Exemplo:

```
   minha_package.pr_rel_saldo[...]
```

Só de uma conferida no tipo da variável `ww_saida`.

Comment: está dando erro: PLS-00201: o identificador 'SAIDA_CURSOR' deve ser declarado

Comment: Sim, provavelmente esse `TYPE` deve estar declarado dentro da sua package também. Tentar colocar package.saida_cursor. Veja se esse tipo esta publicado também.